# Cant take value object - C++

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax-error

I'm having problems taking the value of "p1.media". The value is media: 6.91026e-310 and had to be like 1000, 5000, .... I try too much solutions but anyone works. Here is the code:

> Code of Calculos.h

```
#ifndef CALCULOS_H
#define CALCULOS_H
//includes
#define N 100
using namespace std;

class Calculos {
public:
    Calculos(double T[], int op);  
    Calculos(double T[], int op, double media);
    Calculos(); //constructor por defecto
    void run();

    int op;
    double desvtipica, media, *T;
};
#endif
```

> Code of Calculos.cpp

```
//includes
#include "Calculos.h"
using namespace std;

Calculos::Calculos(double T[], int op) { 
    this->T = T;
    this->op = op;
    desvtipica = 0.0;
};

Calculos::Calculos() { 
}
Calculos::Calculos(double T[], int op, double media) {
    this->T = T;
    this->op = op;
    this->media=media;

};
void Calculos::run() {
    if(op == 1) {   //calcular media
        double suma = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            suma = suma + T[i];
        }   
        media = (double)(suma/N);
    }
    else {  //op=3 calcular desviacion tipica
        desvtipica = 3.0; //partially
    }
};
```

> Code of Ejercicio.cpp

```
//includes
#include "Calculos.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax)
{
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
};

int main() {
    cout << "#datos: " << N << endl;
    double T[N];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
        T[i] = fRand(1.0, 1000.0);
    }

    thread P[2];

    Calculos p1(T, 1);
    P[0] = thread(&Calculos::run, p1);
    P[0].join();
    double m = p1.media;   // Here is the problem. p1.media return bad values
    cout << "media: " << m << endl;
    Calculos p3(T, 3, m);
    P[1] = thread(&Calculos::run, p3);
    P[1].join();

    cout << "Fin\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is important to learn to *simplify* your questions. This is not only for our convenience, it is a vital programming skill. If you reduce the problem to a [minimal compete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you will probably discover the cause along the way, and even if you do not, you will have a very simple problem to show us.

Comment: Also, why do you not correct your compilation errors? Your `double calcular_desvtipica(...)` returns nothing.

Comment: I simplified the code as much as I can. Dont have compilation error now. The problem resides to take "media" value from the object

Comment: You never call `calcular_desvtipica`, so why have you not removed it? You have not simplified this code as much as you can.

Comment: Ok now I remove it and change the constructor removing media = 0.0; but p1.media return bad values

Comment: Please, do not put `using namespace std;` in header files!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue in the way you are passing arguments to the `thread` constructor.

change:

```
   P[0] = thread(&Calculos::run, p1); // creates a copy of p1
```

to:

```
   P[0] = thread(&Calculos::run, std::ref(p1)); // pass p1 by reference
```

Now the output is:

```bash
#datos: 100
media: 547.278
Fin
```

> **Notes**
>
> The arguments to the thread function are **moved or copied** by value. 
>   If a **reference** argument needs to be passed to the thread function,
>   it has to be wrapped (e.g. with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).
>
> Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread
>   (emphasis mine)

---

In your code, `p1.media` is `0` because you didn't do anything with it.
You have worked with a temporary copy of `p1`.

Comment: Your first fix is actually passing by pointer, not reference (same effect, that the thread acts on the same object)

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, Thanks. I have removed that one.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is your use of `std::thread`'s constructor. See the third definition of it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). The line `P[0] = thread(&Calculos::run, p1);` is creating a *copy* of `p1` and then acting on it. Try using a simple reference capture instead:

```
P[0] = thread([&p1](){ p1.run(); });
```

Or, I believe you could also try passing in the address of `p1` like this:

```
P[0] = thread(&Calculos::run, &p1);
```

I know that that syntax works for the likes of `std::bind`, but I am not sure about `std::thread`.